# Visual studio 2022 не видит заголовочные файлы Gtkmm

Tags: visual-studio, gtkmm3

С помощью vcpkg установил Gtkmm. Работаю не от имени администратора, поэтому добавил библиотеки с помощью NuGet (Средства => Диспетчер пакетов NuGet => Консоль диспетчера пакетов) по инструкции. В результате VS увидела заголовочный файл gtkmm-4.0/gtkmm.h(x86-windows\include\gtkmm-4.0), но с остальными возникли проблемы. Файлы подключаемые внутри gtkmm.h уже не видны: glibmm.h(x86-windows\include\glibmm-2.68), gtkmm/object.h(x86-windows\include\gtkmm-4.0\gtkmm) и другие.
Что в таком случае делать ?
Добавлять все пути к файлам в VS ?
Спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"Добавлять все пути к файлам в VS"* - c этого и надо было начинать

Comment: @user7860670 Я попробовал - он мне кучу ошибок и предупреждений выдал при попытке собрать. Наверно больше ста строк.

Comment: Каждое из них следовало прочесть, понять и исправить. "больше ста строк" - это как бы вообще ни о чем